# Not able to build electron app using electron-builder

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am trying to build my app using command electron-builder. I have a dependency node-native-printer which while installing asks for the dependency we would like to select to make it work.
The thing is that it works fine and I am able to select the dependency from terminal while running npm install. But When I runs electron-builder command, it simply fails with the below error.

```
Error: npm.cmd exited with code 1
Output:

> electron-edge-js@10.11.1 install D:\app\node_modules\electron-edge-js
> node tools/install.js

Success: platform check for edge.js: node.js x64 v10.15.3

> node-native-printer@1.0.0-beta.5 install D:\app\node_modules\node-native-printer
> node install/install.js

? Which package do you want to use? (Use arrow keys)
> edge-cs 
  electron-edge-js 
  Not listed 
Error output:
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-native-printer@1.0.0-beta.5 install: `node install/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-native-printer@1.0.0-beta.5 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Vibhor\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-02T07_55_27_454Z-debug.log

    at ChildProcess.childProcess.once.code (D:\app\node_modules\builder-util\src\util.ts:244:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
```

Now how can I resolve this that it automatically selects the electron-edge-js as a dependency?